# i can't perform segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, validation, segue

Below is my code and I want to perform segue based on response string, but couldn't, can someone watch out my code and tell me what's wrong.

and when I am entering value in contact no. textfield,app is terminating with the error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching on object <UITextField: 0x7faae2079980; frame = (20 353; 280 45); text = '9876543210'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+TM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7faae2097250>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7faae2083bd0>>.'
```

Code I have try:

```
 - (IBAction)Register:(id)sender {

if ((uname.text.length==0)&&(uemail.text.length==0)&&(ucontact.text.length==0)&&(upwd.text.length==0)&&(confirmpwd.text.length==0)){

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Can not Register"
                                                  message:@"All the Fields are Mandatory"
                                                 delegate:nil
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
    [alert show];

}
else{


    NSString *emailString = uemail.text;// storing the entered email in a string.
    //Regular expression to checl the email format.
    NSString *emailReg = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";

    NSPredicate *emailTest=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailReg];


     if(([emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailString]!=YES)||[emailString isEqualToString:@""])
    {
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Enter your email in abc@example.com format." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alert show];

        uemail.text = @"";
        return;
    }
}
   NSString *mobile=ucontact.text;
    NSString *numberRegEx = @"([0-9]{10})";
    NSPredicate *numberTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", numberRegEx];
    if ([numberTest evaluateWithObject:ucontact] != YES||[mobile isEqualToString:@""])
    {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Enter a Valid Number." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

        uemail.text = @"";
        return;


}
if ((upwd.text)!=(confirmpwd.text)) {

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Password Do Not Match"
                                                  message:nil
                                                 delegate:nil
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
    [alert show];}


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://108.179.246.128/connectme/service/registration.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *rq = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[rq setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *params=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&email=%@&mobile=%@&passwrd=%@",self->uname.text,self->uemail.text,self->ucontact.text,self->upwd.text];
NSData *postData = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
[rq setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:rq returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; NSLog(@"Login response:%@",str); //getting response

   // [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"activity" sender:self];

    if([str  isEqual: @"Successfully Registered"])
    {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];
    }

    else if([str isEqual:@"Sorry Email address already taken"])
    {

        UIAlertView *alertit=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Can not Register"
                                                     message:@"Email Address already Taken"
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
        [alertit show];
    }
    }
```

Comment: ucontact is textfiled and you can evalute predicate on that .. use `mobile` or `ucontact.text`

Answer (score 1):

For your second question that is crashing, it is because you need to pass the `textField.text` not the `UITextField` object. So it should be `mobile` variable that contain text of textField instead of `ucontact` textField object.

```
[numberTest evaluateWithObject:mobile]
```

Comment: Welcome for your segue you need to give more info, add NSLog where you have added `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];` and check it is executing or not.

Comment: it's not executing,but why ?

Comment: If `NSLog` is not printing that means it is going in else block every time.

Comment: but response is printing in log but not segue part

Comment: @ShikhaSharma Can you show the response of your api it will help to understand what is happing.

Comment: i have resolved it,it was cuz of if else problem. thanks a lot for help :)